# Предподготовка к изучению функционального программирования и Haskell. Книги, статьи, советы

Tags: haskell

Решил для себя, что пришло время окунуться в мир функционального программирования и попробовать изучить язык Haskell.

Я уже немало наслышан про функциональное программирование, про его высокий порог входа. Наслышан, что есть проблемы к терминологией, её переводом и трактовкой на русском.

В настоящий момент, я на базовом уровне знаю C++ и Python (примерно чуть больше года коммерческой разработки на обоих языках в сумме). Помню (при необходимости могу вспомнить) многие вещи из высшей математики универского курса, хотя это было давно.

Еще у меня есть проблема с английским языком: читать документацию могу и перевожу достаточно свободно, но только те темы, которые я более-менее знаю, т.е. чтобы расширить знания. Когда тема абсолютно новая, сперва стараюсь почитать про неё на русском, понять суть, а потом уже читать на английском, уже достаточно быстро разбираясь. Т.е. в английском я не ноль, но и не в совершенстве владею.

Хотелось бы услышать:

1. Какие темы из различных областей: вышки, информатики, программирования, алгоритмов и структур данных (извиняюсь за сумбур в названии этих областей, но это тоже тема достаточно спорная, думаю бОльшинство меня поймёт)  следует предварительно закрепить, подучить, обратить внимание, разобраться. Цель - облегчить самому себе порог входа в функциональное программирование. Т.е. не хочется начать изучать Haskell, тут же увидев там кучу абсолютно неизвестных мне слов и понятий. Хочется быть подготовленным.
2. Какие материалы, какие книги, статьи, возможно форумы посоветуете для выполнения пункта 1. Понятное дело, что лучше читать английский оригинал, но я уже написал, что тяжко порой читать на английском что-то абсолютно новое, хотелось бы начать с чего-то на русском языке.
3. По Haskell я нашел неплохой сайт [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), слышал многие рекомендации. После того, как пройду подготовительную стадию - хочу изучать по нему. Если кто-то мне посоветует что-то лучше (и в особенности на русском) - буду только рад.

Спасибо!

P.S. Надеюсь не будет холивара, что лучше изучать какой-то другой функциональный язык. Я пока остановился на Haskell.

Comment: если вы использовали питоновские lambda, то думаю у вас не будет проблем с изучением, к тому, всё правильно, что вы выбрали именно Haskell

Comment: python'ские: lambda, map, reduce, filter, zip - я использую каждый день в продакшн коде, с этим я более менее знаком и видел их в Haskell (когда просто немного просматривал manual'ы), из него видимо пришли :) Но хотелось бы всё это глубоку изучить. Как бы одна из мотиваций изучения ФП - то, что многие конструкции идут оттуда в императивные языки и хочется поизучать там всё это.

Comment: У меня были проблемы с осознанием монад. Помогла статья «[монады как контейнеры](http://ru-lambda.livejournal.com/12467.html?thread=204723)».

Алсо, кроме упомянутого Learn You A Haskell еще есть хорошая книга [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/). Хороша тем, что не просто излагает теорию, но делает это на решении вполне реальных практических задач.

Answer (score 8):

Никакой высшей математики для программирования на Haskell и функциональных языках вообще знать не нужно. Это стереотип из серии, что C++ древний, Python — жутко тормозной и жрет память гигабайтами, скрипты на Perl совершенно нечитаемы, на PHP пишут только ученики 8-х и 9-х классов и так далее. В действительности у функциональных языков больше общего с процедурными и объектно-ориентированными, чем различий. Вы сами быстро это поймёте, когда начнёте во всём разбираться.

Насчёт материалов. [Learn You a Haskel](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) хороший учебник. Если нужно на русском, обратите внимание на [язык Haskell: о пользе и вреде лени](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_Haskell:_%D0%9E_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) + какие-то ссылки я собирал в этой заметке: [причины, по которым мне нравится Haskell](http://eax.me/why-haskell/). Обратите внимание на блог [*darkus*](http://users.livejournal.com/_darkus_/) — там раз в месяц устраиваются конкурсы по функциональному программированию, которые помогут вам отточить владение Хаскелем. Из форумов могу предложить [функциональные и логические языки](http://it-talk.org/forum49.html).

Comment: Насчёт "знать не нужно", так правильней сказать "знание не является обязательным". А знать математику желательно при программировании на любом языке (php и 1С тут не исключение).

Comment: Программировать на хаскеле, не зная алгебры, это как создавать игры при помощи высоко абстрагированных функций какого-нибудь суперфреймворка, и при этом не уметь делать графику при помощи операций над векторами и матрицами. Можно, только зачем? На хаскеле пишут ради искусства. Писать на нем не ради внутренней красоты - пустая трата времени. Это попахивает показной элитарностью, когда людихотят не действительно разбираться в хаскеле, а всем говорить о том, что они в нем разбираются.

Answer (score 5):

Пришли не из него, а из общих предков. Есть книги по Haskell, среди них, наверняка есть переводы, есть книги на русском, например Душкина. Что касается лямбда- и комбинаторных затей, то я бы порекомендовал J.Harrison Introduction to Functional Programming, правда там ML, не haskell (проект перевода её на русский -- [funprog-ru](http://code.google.com/p/funprog-ru/)). В TMR-13 ([The Monad.Reader Issue 13](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf)) статья Typeclassopedia (для понимания классов типов). Из форумов -- есть на rsdn форум по декларативному программированию.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие темы из различных областей: вышки, информатики, программирования, алгоритмов и структур данных (извиняюсь за сумбур в названии этих областей, но это тоже тема достаточно спорная, думаю бОльшинство меня поймёт) следует предварительно закрепить, подучить, обратить внимание, разобраться.

Можно обратить внимание на «[теорию категорий для программистов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/245797/)», хотя это не обязательно.

Касаемо изучения самого языка, https://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/book/toc.html выглядит неплохим пособием.

Кроме материалов, упомянутых в других ответах, советую обратить внимание на замечательную статью: «[What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/)», в которой разбираются многие прикладные аспекты языка.